# Github gl-exporter tool not found

Tags: github, gitlab

I can't seem to find where we can download the gl-exporter tool that is being referred at https://github.github.com/enterprise-migrations/#/./2.2.2.1-export-from-gitlab-guide.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yeah. me too. the link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can know find `gl-exporter` here: https://github.com/ps-accreditation/ps-accreditation-cms/releases. Grab the `gl-exporter-latest.tar.gz` file.

Comment: It's not working at this link anymore either... where is it now located?

Comment: This link works, but you need to have access to the ps-accredition organization: https://github.com/ps-accreditation/ Access to this organization if provided by GitHub to (possibly wannabe) official partners.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been using the `gh actions-importer` instead and it works flawlessly.